# Possible to start a SurfaceView with a Game Thread anytime other than at startup of the program?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I've read several example programs and tutorials to try and solve my problem but they all seem to go the same way.  I've used a couple Activities and xml documents to create a menu that loads when my game starts.  When the user clicks the "Start The Game" button, it loads a new Activity that sets the view with my game thread and all of the game properties.  I know this activity works because I've run it alone as its own project, but every way I've tried to start it after the Menu, I get a nullPointerException and it force closes.  I read the SurfaceViewOverlay tutorial and attempted to use that implementation, but I'm using a SurfaceView, not a GLSurfaceView.  I'm debating rewriting my entire program to use OpenGL but I figured I would see if anyone else knows what I'm doing wrong here.  If you need the code snippets I can paste some here, but it's not really the specific code that's wrong, I think it's the way I'm using(abusing) the language...

Thanks for any help,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem quite some time ago, but figured I would come back and give an answer to anyone else having my problem.  When using a SurfaceView it must be part of the activity that created it and be in some sort of FrameLayout in the xml for that activity.

For example:

```
    <com.example.MySurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

You can add any other layout elements you would like, but this is required to create the SurfaceView.  I hope this helps anyone else who had my problem, for any further questions just ask and I'll be sure to elaborate if necessary.